# Showing widget when phone is locked

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm trying to figure out how can I show some information when the phone is locked (using password or block sequence).

The result that I'm trying to reach is the one shown in the picture below:

[image]

As you can see the widget on top is shown also if the phone is locked.

Is there any way for showing programmatically a widget like that?

Comment: Does the widget (in sample picture) appear only when the phone is locked?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't try the : [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appventive.ice)

Answer (score 0):

Since Android 4.2, it is possible to add home screen app widgets to the lock screen of an Android device. To enable your widget for the look screen you need to add keyguard category in the android:widgetCategory attribute in the AppWidgetProviderInfo XML file. The following code shows an example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <appwidget-provider 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0" >

</appwidget-provider>
```